# Can a SOAP Client Have A Secondary Endpoint?

Tags: c#, soap-client

I have a Windows application that uses soap to communicate with an Internet service. The endpoint is defined in the app.config file.

```
<client>
  <endpoint address="http://www.the_url.com/MyService/Service.asmx" binding="basicHttpBinding"
    bindingConfiguration="ClaimServiceSoap" contract="namespace.ClaimServiceSoap"
    name="ClaimServiceSoap" />
</client>
```

Recently, the machine hosting the service went down, and the service was setup at a different URL. The client edited their hosts file to redirect the URL, but has asked me if I can fail to a backup url automatically. Can a secondary, or alternate endpoint be added to the app.config?

Comment: A better way would be to provide failover on the server side—but this would probably be more expensive too. Also interested in answers.